# I can annoy the hell out of people in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Most things in chat are rate-limited, however edits are not. Each new edit to a post pings a user. Here's an autohotkey script:

```
Loop 100
{
  Send {Up}!{Enter}
}
```

Shouldn't edits be rate-limited too? Or pings from the same post limited in some way?

Comment: I saw the title and thought this was a brag post or something.  Funny.

Comment: I would personally prefer if an edit would not repeat the ping, but that suggestion is now my most-downvoted post on MSO, so I'm in the minority there.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables *Ninja-brag-post*

Comment: My initial thought is that the whole "You only can edit for 2 minutes" is kinda meant as an alternative to a rate limit but that does little to the whole point within those 2 minutes.

Comment: Oh god no. If we're going to do anything just limit how many times a message can ping, say, no pings after the second edit. Chat's message rate limit is annoying enough

Comment: [Indeed](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/77?m=419087#419087).

Comment: @TimStone [Indeed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/8124501/history)

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things. Actually, I think the entire Bridge is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: Aww.  We're only a *little* crazy, I swear!

Comment: @fbueckert Crazy is a relative thing.

Comment: why @fredley *whhhhyyyyyyyyyyy*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Building currently; now with even more throttling :)

Comment: I hope it's a more sane limit than the one message per second limit?

Comment: @Ben and what would you define as "sane" here? If you're editing more than one a second, *you're doing something wrong*...

Comment: @BenBrocka I agree. The 1-message per second throttle should only kick in after the *second* message IMO, so I can do things like `look at this: \ [oneboxlink]`

Comment: @fredley as a more global tweak to throttling, that could indeed probably work

Comment: @MarcGravell brb, asking new question

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167747/150214