# Chat throttling should kick in after the second message

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, throttling

In a [recent discussion about throttling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167743/150214), I suggested that throttling should kick in after the *second* message. This allows for:

- Posting things along the lines of `look at this: \ [onebox link]` without things breaking up your message
- Rapid edits (I believe a 1-second throttle is being applied here too)

While still preventing spamming. It's a small change that could kill a few annoyances with chat.

Comment: I post in the form of (message) (onebox) all the time and get rate limited all the time. Worst is when I ask if X is a dupe of Y, which requires 3/4 messages: "Is X [Q] a dupe of this: [Q2]"

Comment: @BenBrocka Ideally some kind of transactional model for posts could be implemented `[START_TRANSACTION] \ Is this: \ [Q1] \ A dupe of this: \ [Q2] \ ? \ [COMMIT]`

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132483/can-i-please-be-trusted-to-not-to-script-a-bot-that-dumps-an-endless-stream-of-s)

Comment: Current workflow is "is this" "[Q1]" *swearing* "A dupe of:" *more swearing* [Q2] *pause* "@rate limit DIAF"

Comment: @BenBrocka Clearly a no then...

Comment: @fredley If you try `[Q1] \ is this a dupe of: \ [Q2]` you should no longer run into problems unless you're really fast in posting Q2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ok; I'm game... I've enabled a "grace" system that relaxes the rules *just a little* (not much) - and only applies to the "new" and "edit" actions. It allows quick 2-liners, or ninja edits - but after that one action, you're back to normal rules. Deploying now. Let me know your opinions...

Comment: *Off to go and test the limits of 'just a little'...*

Comment: w00t! Thx. You're awesome.